# optimizing dynamic programming in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have a problem with a dynamic programming solution which I'm trying to implement in matlab and was trying to see if there's a better (run-time-wise) implementation than the one I could come up with.

The problem (all values are in the real):
input: let X be a T-by-d matrix, W be a k-by-d matrix and A by a k-by-k matrix.
output: Y T-by-1 array s.t for row i in X Y(i) is the number of a row in W which maximizes our goal.

A(i,j) gives us the cost of choosing row j if the previous row we chose was i.

To calculate the weight of the output, for each row i in X we sum the dot-product of the Y(i) row of W and add the relevant cost from A.

Our goal is to maximaize the said weight.

Dynamic solution:

- instantiate a k-by-T matrix
- Fill the first column of the matrix with the results of dot-producting the first row of X with each row of W
- for each of the same columns (denote as i) fill with the dot-producting of the i row of X with each row of W and add the cost of A(j,i) where j is the row index of the cell in previous column with maximum value
- backtrack from the last column, each time choosing the row index of the cell with the highest value

Matlab implementation (with instantiation of variables):

```
T = 8;
d = 10;
k = 20;
X = rand(T,d);
W = rand(k,d);
A = rand(k);
Y = zeros(T,1);
weight_table = zeros(k,T);

weight_table(:,1) = W*X(1,:)';

for t = 2 : T
    [~, prev_ind] = max(weight_table(:,t-1));
    weight_table(:,t) = W*X(t,:)' + A(:,prev_ind);
end

[~, Y] = max(weight_table);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is data dependency across iterations, I would advise keeping the loop, but pre-calculate few things like the product of `W` and transpose of each row of `X`. This is done here (showing just the `weight_table` calculation part as the rest of the code stays the same as in the original post) -

```
weight_table = zeros(k,T);
weight_table(:,1) = W*X(1,:)';
WXt = W*X.'; %//' Pre-calculate
for t = 2 : T
    [~, prev_ind] = max(weight_table(:,t-1));
    weight_table(:,t) = WXt(:,t) + A(:,prev_ind); %// Use pre-calculated values and thus avoid that multiplication across each iteration
end
```

For bigger inputs like - `T = 800; d = 1000; k = 2000;`, I am getting `8-10x` performance improvement with it on my system.

Comment: One more optimization is to store `weight_table(:,t)` as a temporary variable and use it in the next iteration. But my profiler suggests this is even a bit slower than directly accessing the large matrix twice. Perhaps the benefit will be seen if OP wants more matrix read/write operations in one loop.

Comment: @Yvon That's a good suggestion, but since the values are finally needed in `weight_table` anyway, I guess the benefits might not be there.